# SGDClassifier and PCA

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

In [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#tips-on-practical-use) Mentioned:

> If you apply SGD to features extracted using PCA we found that it is
>   often wise to scale the feature values by some constant c such that
>   the average L2 norm of the training data equals one.

I don't get how can i scale the feature values by some constant c. Would you please write some line of python code for this scaling?

Comment: It just mean to multiply by a constant c.

Comment: that the average L2 norm of the training data equals one

Comment: 1) calculate the l2 norm of an instance 2) calculate the l2 norm of all you instance 3) average them 4) multiply all you instances by ten, how that average change ? 5) what is the c that would give an average of 1 ? 6) multiply all your instances by that c...

Comment: @Rezaenergy Did you manage to come up with a pseudocode / Python code to scale the PCA features by c as advised in the Scikit documentation? I am using PCA before SGDClassifier (log loss).